# Google Apps Script reports API example code returning null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-workspace

I'm trying to use [this snippet of App Script code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-reports#generate_user_usage_report) that prints out some values from the Reports API. I tweaked it slightly, like so:

```
function testDocsOwned() {
  var today = new Date();
  var oneWeekAgo = new Date(today.getTime() - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  var timezone = Session.getTimeZone();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(oneWeekAgo, timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

  var parameters = [
    'accounts:last_login_time',
    'gmail:num_emails_received',
    'docs:num_docs'
  ];
  var rows = [];
  var pageToken;
  var page;
  do {
    page = AdminReports.UserUsageReport.get('all', date, {
      parameters: parameters.join(','),
      maxResults: 500,
      pageToken: pageToken
    });
    var reports = page.usageReports;
    if (reports) {
      for (var i = 0; i < reports.length; i++) {
        var report = reports[i];
        var parameterValues = getParameterValues(report.parameters);
        var row = [
          report.date,
          report.entity.userEmail,
          parameterValues['accounts:last_login_time'],
          parameterValues['gmail:num_emails_received'],
          parameterValues['docs:num_docs']
        ];
        rows.push(row);
      }
    }
    pageToken = page.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
    console.log(rows);
}
```

When this code runs, the `docs_owned` property returns `null` and `num_emails_recieved` is 0; and I've verified these accounts have mail and drive docs. Docs were created and emails were received in the last six months.

Comment: At the top of that page you linked it says, `Note: This is an advanced service that must be enabled before use.`.  Did you do that?

Comment: Yeah, the service is enabled. I have the last login dates coming through fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my working code (it's similar but not quite the same):

```
function runLoginActivityReport(pageToken) {
  var today = new Date();
  var oneWeekAgo = new Date(today.getTime() -30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  var timezone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(oneWeekAgo, timezone, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

  var parameters = [
    'accounts:last_login_time',
    'drive:num_items_created'
  ];
  var rows = [];
  var recordCollection = [];
  var page;

  page = AdminReports.UserUsageReport.get('all', date, {
    parameters: parameters.join(','),
    maxResults: 500,
    pageToken: pageToken
  });
  var reports = page.usageReports;

  if (page.warnings) {
    for (var q = 0; q < page.warnings.length; q++) {
      var warning = page.warnings[q];
      Logger.log(warning.message);
    }
  }
// there was some logic here
  return page.nextPageToken;
}
```